# Change/declare a constant in setup and use it in loop

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, variables

I want to change or declare a constant in the `setup()` and then, I want to access it in the `loop()`.

I have searched a lot, but the only questions I found could be solved by declaring the constant in the beginning of the program. That doesn't work for me because I am using the Adafruit BMP388 and I can't use the pressure before `setup()`.

I also tried declaring the variable before `setup()` and changing it inside `setup()`, but it didn't change when I used it in `loop()`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: how are we to know that you actually changed it in loop()?

Comment: I didn't change it in loop(), I have to access it there. I want to change it in setup()

Comment: look at the `fade` sketch in arduino IDE example sketches

Comment: how are we to know that you actually changed it in setup()?

Comment: I want to use it in loop(): I need the startpressure (declared in setup()) and compare it to the current pressure

Comment: the title of your post does not match the content of your post ... title asks about a `variable`, content asks about a `constant` ... i suggest that you research the difference

Comment: Constants cannot, by definition, be changed. Do you mean variables?

Comment: *I also tried declaring the variable before the setup() and changing it inside the setup(), but it didn't change when I used it in the loop().* - Can you show this code? A variable, changed in setup, would stay changed. Unless you declared it twice (shadowed it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not going to get good answers without showing your code, but maybe this is a good guess of what you want:

why not try something roughly like this (untested and incomplete)?

```
Adafruit_BMP3XX bmp;
float startPressure;
float difference;

void setup() {
  bmp.begin_I2C();
  startPressure = bmp.readPressure();
} 

void loop() {
  difference = startPressure - bmp.readPressure();
}
```

Or, better:

```
Adafruit_BMP3XX bmp;

void setup() {
  bmp.begin_I2C();
} 

void loop() {
  static const float startPressure = bmp.readPressure();
  static float difference;
  difference = startPressure - bmp.readPressure();
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is the direction he's going in.  But if he is, you could move float startPressure; into the loop(), perform startPressure = bmp.readPressure(); as part of its initialization, and make it static and const.
As in: static const float startPressure = bmp.readPressure();
This would behave as what you have but would limit startPressure to the only scope it's used in.

Comment: @timemage: True, and better, but it would require an explanation of "static", and I don't feel up to it 8-). I will add it though.

Comment: `difference` does not need to be `static`.

Comment: Yeah, and it technically isn't "constant" in C++ terms.  But it seems to be in the spirit of the question so far as I understand the question.

Comment: @Edgar-Bonet: No, doesn't have to be in the example, but who knows if he wants it to remain the same over several loops in his code.